# How i can deal with Laravel navigation through bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am having links in routes already but I want to create a customer bootsrap. What will be the good way to do it.

Comment: Try to be more clear about your question. Your question is unclear and lacks example

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have al the back-end logic, you can easily render the navigation buttons with this package: https://github.com/appstract/laravel-bootstrap-components

1. Install the package and add the alias in config/app.php:

   `'BootstrapComponents' => Appstract\BootstrapComponents\BootstrapComponentsFacade::class`
2. Now return the render code with a variable to your view, where $items is your collection and $page is the current page

   `return view('myview', ['pagination' => BootstrapComponents::pagination($items, $page, $perPage))`
3. Place `{{ $pagination }}` in your view where you want it to display